# how to use array on formData.append

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

This is my ajax code

```
var formData = new FormData();
$a = array = ['1', '7'];
formData.append('kpmConfigDt1', $a);

$.ajax({
    url: '<?= base_url() ?>hr_pms/kpmConfigDtl_list1',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      .........
    }
});
```

this my code, I want to use $a as the value of my formData.append, but it doesn't work, can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use a for loop to append

```
$length = count($a);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  formData.append('kpmConfigDt1', $a[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but still I doesn't work, I have this controller that accept the value from formData





<!-- -->

public function kpmConfigDtl_list1(){
        
        $kpmConfigDt = $this->input->post('kpmConfigDt1');
        $kpmConfigDt2 = $this->pms_model->get_kpmConfigDt2($kpmConfigDt);
        echo json_encode($kpmConfigDt2);
    }

Answer (score 0):

you need to serialize the array:

```
formData.append('name',array.toString());
```

Then you can recreate it on the php side

```
explode(',',$array);
```

I use the following query in a function designed to get all the form data:

```
var formData = new FormData();
$('#formId').find("input, textarea, select").each(function(){

    ...

    if(Array.isArray($(this).val())){
       formData.append(
          $(this).attr('name'),
          $(this).val().toString()
       ); 
    }

    ...

});
```